# How to show all rows from database

Tags: android

In the code below, I'm getting only the last row in my database, i.e. first name and last name of the last row in my DB. My question is: how do I change this code in order to get all the results printed?

```
package samples.directory;      

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class clanguage extends Activity {
protected Cursor c;
protected SQLiteDatabase db;


protected TextView employeeName;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webdesign);
    WebView engine = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_engine);

    db = (new DatabaseHelper(this)).getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT firstName, lastName FROM employee", null);
    if (c != null ) {
        if  (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                String firstName= c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("firstName"));
                String lastName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("lastName "));                                                   
                String data = "<html>" +
                    "<body><table border=2> <tr> <td>"+firstName+"</td>+                                
                    <td>"+lastName+"</td></tr></body></html>";

                engine.loadData(data, "text/html", "UTF-8");

            }while (c.moveToNext());
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this way

```
StringBuffer data = new StringBuffer("<html>");
data.append("<body><table border=2>");
do {

    String firstName= c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("firstName"));
    String lastName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("lastName "));

    data.append("<tr> <td>"+firstName+"</td><td>"+lastName+"</td></tr>");

}while (c.moveToNext());
data.append("</table></body></html>");
engine.loadData(data, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

you everytime override content of data object and load it.

Comment: The method loadData(String, String, String) in the type WebView is not applicable for the arguments (StringBuffer, String, String)

Comment: hey u got any idea abt this errorThe method loadData(String, String, String) in the type WebView is not applicable for the arguments (StringBuffer, String, String)...i cant even run the appln because of this error

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work.

```
 String data = "<html>" +
    "<body><table border=2> ";
if  (c.moveToFirst()) {

      do {

      String firstName= c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("firstName"));

      String lastName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("lastName "));

      data  += "<tr> <td>"+firstName+"</td>+
     <td>"+lastName+"</td></tr>";

      }while (c.moveToNext());
 data  += "</table></body></html>";
 engine.loadData(data, "text/html", "UTF-8");
}
```

Comment: the code works but its creating an error and forceclosing my application....the error says  12-09 12:47:18.321: E/CursorWindow(218): Bad request for field slot 0,-1. numRows = 34, numColumns = 2

Comment: probably firstName is not present in your table. c.getColumnIndex("firstName") is returning -1. check your DB and the contents of your table.

Comment: Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT firstName, lastName FROM employee", null);       is it because of any error from this statement??

Comment: String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employee(" + "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + "firstName TEXT, " + "city TEXT, " + "lastName TEXT)";db.execSQL(sql);

Comment: i have obviously given firstName in DB...Could it be any other reason?

Comment: i have cheked it with only firstName and it works but when i include first and language in Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT firstName, lastName FROM employee", null); then it shows the same error E/CursorWindow(218): Bad request for field slot 0,-1. numRows = 34, numColumns = 2 ending in forceclose of application